Set_Model_State does not move my TurtleBot2
I am currently trying to create/migrate Q-Learning scripts for my TurtleBot2 in gazebo (for ROS2/Humble) and came to a problem which I cant solve. In a Python file I have created a couple of methods for actions and states and a method called robotSetPos:
def robotSetPos(self, setPosPub, x, y, theta):
    self.get_logger().info(f"Setting position to x: {x}, y: {y}, theta: {theta}")
    # Create a ModelState message to hold the new robot state
    checkpoint = ModelState()


    checkpoint.model_name = 'robot'

    # Set the position of the robot
    checkpoint.pose.position.x = x
    checkpoint.pose.position.y = y
    checkpoint.pose.position.z = 0.0  # Assuming the robot is on a flat surface

    # Convert the orientation from Euler angles to quaternions
    qx = math.sin(0.0) * math.cos(0.0) * math.cos(math.radians(theta) / 2) - math.cos(0.0) * math.sin(0.0) * math.sin(math.radians(theta) / 2)
    qy = math.cos(0.0) * math.sin(0.0) * math.cos(math.radians(theta) / 2) + math.sin(0.0) * math.cos(0.0) * math.sin(math.radians(theta) / 2)
    qz = math.cos(0.0) * math.cos(0.0) * math.sin(math.radians(theta) / 2) - math.sin(0.0) * math.sin(0.0) * math.cos(math.radians(theta) / 2)
    qw = math.cos(0.0) * math.cos(0.0) * math.cos(math.radians(theta) / 2) + math.sin(0.0) * math.sin(0.0) * math.sin(math.radians(theta) / 2)
    checkpoint.pose.orientation = Quaternion(x=qx, y=qy, z=qz, w=qw)

    # Set the twist (linear and angular velocity) to zero
    checkpoint.twist.linear.x = 0.0
    checkpoint.twist.linear.y = 0.0
    checkpoint.twist.linear.z = 0.0
    checkpoint.twist.angular.x = 0.0
    checkpoint.twist.angular.y = 0.0
    checkpoint.twist.angular.z = 0.0

    # Publish the new robot state
    setPosPub.publish(checkpoint)
    self.get_logger().info("Published new robot state")

    return (x, y, theta)

In another file I have imported the file containing the robotSetPos method, also imported ModelState and created a publisher         self.setPosPub = self.create_publisher(ModelState, '/gazebo/set_model_state', 10)
but as soon as the code reaches the point where the robotSetPos method is called, it sets the right coordinates and orientation, but the robot does not move. I have already checked the model_name which is properly defined and also created this code in order to check for the model_state which I ran simultanously with my script:
import rclpy
from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetModelState

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = rclpy.create_node('check_model_state')

    client = node.create_client(GetModelState, '/gazebo/get_model_state')
    while not client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
        node.get_logger().info('service not available, waiting again...')

    request = GetModelState.Request()
    request.model_name = 'robot'  

    future = client.call_async(request)
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(node, future)

    if future.result() is not None:
        state = future.result()
        node.get_logger().info(f'Model state: {state}')
    else:
        node.get_logger().error('Failed to get model state')

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

which kept telling me that the service is unavailable and waiting again although its shown under the topic/service list. I am spawning the robot through a launch file containing spawn_entity.py and the robot is visualized properly in gazebo. Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!
